# List is out of range why?

Tags: python

Every time I input 1 it will say list index out of range
I ended up putting a if statement that said if input is 1 print January 
How can I make this program work with out the first if statement

```
months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]
months_nums=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
user_input= int(input("Enter month: "))
while user_input != 0:
    for i in months_nums:
        if user_input == months_nums[i]:
            print(months[i])
            break
    user_input= int(input("Enter months: "))
```

Comment: `for i in months_nums: if user_input == months_nums[i]:` this doesn't do what you think, change your `if` to `if user_input == months_nums`

Comment: Do you really need a `months_nums` list at all? if `user_input` is "1" you can get "January" by simply doing `months[user_input-1]`.

Comment: You can also just "waste" a few bytes and stick a dummy month name at position 0 of your list: `[None, "January", "February", ... ]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to print the month name based on a continuously prompted user input, why not use this?

```
user_input= int(input("Enter month: "))

while user_input != 0:
    print(months[user_input-1])
    user_input= int(input("Enter months: "))
```

This takes advantage of the order in the array `month` - month name index in that array is simply the input number - 1.

The reason why your loop didn't work is actually a small and not that visible bug. `for i in months_nums:` means you're literally fetching the elements of `months_nums`, not indices. In other words `i = 1,2,3,..,12` not `0,1,2,..11`.

When looking for January you ask for the first element which is never found because `i` in `months_nums[i]` will never have a value `0` and fetch you month number 1. On the other hand it will eventually reach value 12 and the last index of `month_nums` is 11 - which is when it throws an error.

You can fix this issue in your original loop by using `i` as elements which they actually are, rather then indices in the `if` statement:

```
user_input= int(input("Enter month: "))
while user_input != 0:
    for i in months_nums:
        if user_input == i:
            print(months[i-1])
            break
    user_input= int(input("Enter months: "))
```

This one still takes advantage of ordering in `months` so the printed value has an index of `i-1`.

Comment: Can you explain to me why the for loop one wont work. I understand the code you put out.. I just was wondering why the for loop cant read the number 1 but all the other numbers are working

Comment: Sure, just a minute.

Comment: Also, does this make me dumb for doing it the original way? -.- Also I am a beginner with no experience..

Comment: Not at all :) don't know about the others but I had my fair share of horrible programming ideas as a beginner :D I even started the think that the worse the beginning the better the later part.. :))

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have this kind of conversations :) I updated the answer - let me know if it is still unclear. Also, this is not such a bad design, especially not when you're used to or started with traditional for loops in other languages. Good luck with your progress :)

Comment: Goodness.. The mistake I had made was easy now that you have broken it down for me.. Thank you so much!!! Yeah before I had to put another if statement saying if user_input == months[0]: print(months[0] break, it worked for sure but I knew there was a better way constructing this program! Thanks again! :))))))))

Comment: Yep, that kind of `if` would do the job too. Glad to help :))) Just code, think, try stuff out and it will get all better. Learn and try new things, especially ones characteristic for a given language, it's fun. Don't want to preach, but that's what I've been taught ;) :))

Comment: NO! please teach me whatever you think that will help me on my journey.. Im not the best but im willing to work my butt off to understand and get it!!! Is there anyway to add friends here so I could stay in contact? (Im not going to blow up your inbox and stuff everyday.. only when Im for real stuck haha. )

Comment: :)) it's a fun journey, and don't think about who's better and who's worse, to me it's all hard work. Or maybe 90% hard work, and 90% is a lot! :D I don't think this is possible on SO - just checked. Seems all we can do for now is regular questions and public chats. Or do you know a way?

Comment: Sent you one :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has to do with the way you are iterating the indices and checking if a user's input matches the month in your months_num list.

`if user_input == months_nums[i]` wouldn't work because if a user inputs `1` months will be `February` cause lists count from `0`.

Instead you should do the following:

```
months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]
months_nums=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

options = dict(zip(months_num, months))

user_input= int(input("Enter month: "))

try:
    print(options[user_input])
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]
months_nums=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
user_input= int(input("Enter month: "))
while user_input != 0:
    if user_input in months_nums:
        print(months[user_input-1])
        break
    user_input= int(input("Enter months: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
months= ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
        "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]
months_nums=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
user_input= int(input("Enter month: "))
while user_input != 0:
for i in months_nums:
    if user_input == i:
        print(months[i-1])
        break
user_input= int(input("Enter months: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a list why not use the datetime library:

```
import datetime

user_input = int(input("Enter month: "))

while user_input != 0: 
    month = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(user_input),"%m")
    print(month.strftime("%B"))
    user_input= int(input("Enter months: "))
```

Basically you can read more about strftime which prints a datetime object in a specific way: e.g. datetime.strftime("%B") gives month. You also need strptime which reads a date from a string, e.g. datetime.strptime("31/12/1999","%d/%m/%Y"),and we only need to read the month in this case.

---

However, I would probably check if input is an integer and then check if it is within the range 1-12 if not quit. Something like this this:

```
import datetime

# Start a loop
while True:

    # Ask for a number until you get one
    while True:
        user_input= input("Enter months: ")
        try:
            user_input = int(user_input)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("you must enter an integer")

    # Break if user input not in range
    if user_input not in range(1,12):
        break

    # Get current month    
    month = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(user_input),"%m")

    # Print
    print(month.strftime("%B"))
```